# How I can set a form pop out when I click a button in VC++2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, forms

I am working on a homework; I put everything in a folder and upload to a site. Please download it and help. 
 I follow my teacher example, but it must have something missing. My code is able to be compiled, but does not able to  pop out the form as I excepted.

Please help ! Thanks

Code link  http://sharesend.com/xkpm2

Comment: That's not how Stack Overflow works. We're not going to do the assignment for you. Please show the part of the code that you have a problem with right here in the question and show what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: You might misunderstand why I upload the file. I upload the file because there are a few forms and I don't know which part is the problem. I hope you understand my situation and what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the error.  I forget to add

```
myForm2->ShowDialog()
```

to show my form